# Configuration Manager is not saving in app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configurationmanager

I have this app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conexx" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.2 ;Initial Catalog   =ifdcontroladoria3 ;uid =sa;pwd = admin2012" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"   sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup></configuration>
```

I m  trying to update this connectring with this C# :

```
  coneydstr = @"Data Source=" + comboBox1.Text + ";Initial Catalog =" + cmbBancos.Text + ";uid =" + txtUsuario.Text + ";pwd =" + txtPassword.Text;
        try
         { coneyd.ConnectionString = coneydstr; 
           coneyd.Open(); 
           funciona = true;
           lblStringSalida.Text = coneydstr;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {  MessageBox.Show(coneyd + ex.Message.ToString());  }

        if (funciona)
        { 
          Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
          config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["conexx"].ConnectionString = coneydstr;
          config.Save();   
        }
```

but is not making update ,

```
 using System.Configuration;
```

is in the header and the reference , what is wrong?????

I have write wrong the problem, i want to store the connectionstring somewhere maybe app.config or other file , and change the string in another install or when then server or user changes. What the right way to do this???

Comment: What do you mean by "is not making update"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your problem most likely is that you're looking at the *wrong file*. Look at the `config.FilePath` property in the debugger - it will tell you **exactly** which file you're dealing with here and now.

When you run this code in Visual Studio, your code will change the `Yourapplication.exe.config` inside your `project\bin\debug` directory - it will ***NOT*** change the `app.config` in your project directory!

So when you run your code - after the `config.Save()`, have a look at your project's `\bin\debug` directory and the config file inside there - are those values properly updated?

Comment: Then there is a similar problem when the program is installed - an "ordinary user" is not allowed to change stuff in /program files on a whim. There will then magically appear a new config file somewhere in the user's folders (can't remember the path). To make debugging even more difficult; the last folder of this path changes with pseudo random for every installation.

Comment: It's not pseudo random, its generated from the [AppDomain's Evidence property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593/c-application-settings-where-are-they-stored). You could potentially control it if you explicitly set it.